# How do i add to a nested array within a struct

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix, arrays

I am unable to add elements to a array within the struct
struct D {
        string name;
        address key;
    }
    struct Aone {
        string aid;
        B[] blist;
       D[] dlist;
    }
    struct B{
        string bdesc;
        bool bstatus;
        C[] clist;
    }

```
struct C{
    uint createTime;
    string cdesc;
    bool rstatus;
    string ctype;   
}
```

mapping(string => Aone) A;

I am need to add  items to struct c based on aid provided
function rptC(string _aid, string _c) public {
        B[] storage bhist = A[_aid].blist;

```
        if(bhist.length > 0 && bhist[bhist.length-1].bstatus==false) {
            bhist[bhist.length-1].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        } else if(bhist[bhist.length-1].bstatus==true) {
            bhist[bhist.length].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        } else {
            bhist[0].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        }
}
```

I keep getting a invalid json rpc error.
I am new to Solidity and need help

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
clist.push(c(now,_problem,false,"")
```

You're pushing a c (shouldn't it be a C?) struct with 4 fields, but the struct has only 3 fields.

Comment: I am sorry . When i wrote the question i missed the 4th field in struct c struct C{
    uint createTime;
    string cdesc; bool rstatus,
    string ctype;   
} . Also it should capital C ..wrote it incorrectly as small c in the question

Answer (score 0):

This is difficult to answer you with this short parth of your source code but are you sure that the `bhist` struct already exist before adding the `clist`?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem:

```
B[] storage bhist = A[_aid].blist
```

You're using A has a mapping, not has a struct.

I made a few changes, and now the following code is working on remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract Test {

    mapping ( string => B[] ) A;

    struct B {
        string bdesc;
        bool bstatus;
        C[] clist;
    }

    struct C {
        uint createTime;
        string cdesc;
        bool rstatus;
        string ctype;   
    }

    function rptC(string _aid, string _c) public {
        B[] storage bhist = A[_aid];
        if(bhist.length > 0 && bhist[bhist.length-1].bstatus==false) {
            bhist[bhist.length-1].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        } else if(bhist[bhist.length-1].bstatus==true) {
            bhist[bhist.length].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        } else {
            bhist[0].clist.push(C(now,_c,false,""));
        }
    }
}
```

Does this help?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However i am still not sure how to update the below as per your instruction I am unable to add elements to a array within the struct